# Dúvida quanto a endereço de memória e ponteiro

Tags: c

O retorno da função printf no código abaixo, representa o endereço de memória ocupado por **a**?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int a = 123;
    int *b = &a;

    printf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d", b);
    printf("%d", *b);
}
```

- O primeiro printf é o mesmo que falar: **a** ocupa o endereço de
  memória **xxxx**?
- O segundo printf é o mesmo que falar: o ponteiro **b** aponta para o endereço **a**?
- O terceiro printf é o mesmo que falar: o endereço de memória de **b** é **xxxx**?

Comment: Por favor, não fique repetindo a mesma pergunta, lá na anterior tem os *links* onde já existe resposta para estas questões.